# is there any better way to adjust gerrit insert code size base on rule and exclude file path?

Tags: jenkins, prolog, gerrit

we have applied one submit rule to pop up manager-approval if inserted code  size > 300 lines, that works well. But now team has further request:
1.  need exclude some file path like 3rd party's file.
2.  need define different ratio for java/python/html change, like 0.8 for java and 0.6 for html so 100 lines insertion only count as 80 for java and 60 for html.

so far no good solution to achieve this:

a.  in PROLOG submit rule call further new function to went through all file and calculate rule and return the real insert line number,  how to use PRLOG to call python's function is one blocking issue.
b.  change gerrit commit_stats() to  to went through all files and calculate rule and return the real insert line number,  this way need study gerrit code 1st.

not sure if anyone else ever achieve this with any other solution.

thanks in advance！！

Answer (score 1):

for others' reference:

we use Jenkins/gerrit together to achieve the goal.
1. gerrit trigger jenkins for patchset-create.
2. after CI job done, jenkins further calculates real code size, if code size less than defined threshold, jenkins auto update new code approval label; if still big than threshold, leave the code approval label to management team to approve.